# Saving multiple entities using ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a view that takes in an `IEnumerable<User>` and for every user it pumps out an editor with a save button at the bottom of the page. My post action takes in an `IEnumerable<User>` but for some reason this value is always null.

Here is my view (shortened)

```
@model IEnumerable<User>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ViewUsers", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        foreach (var item in Model) {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Username)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.IsAdmin)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.GoldCoins)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
        <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Save"/></td></tr>
    }
```

My action:

```
 public ActionResult ViewUsers()
        {
            IEnumerable<User> users = userService.GetUsers();
            return View(users.ToList());
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ViewUsers(List<User> users)
        {
                foreach (User u in users)
                {
                    userService.Save(u);
                }
            return RedirectToAction("ViewUsers");
        }
```

I know the save method works as it works with single entities just fine. It throws the error on the loop because 'users' is null.

Comment: The model binder doesn't know that you are sending it a collection because of how you used the editor and display html helpers.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use the editor HTML helpers like this example:

```
@model List<User>
@using (Html.BeginForm("ViewUsers", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) {
       @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].Username)
       @:Is Admin: @Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].IsAdmin)
       @:Gold Coins: @Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].GoldCoins)
    }
    <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
}
```

Note: I stripped out the table tags to make it simpler to read.  The gist is that binding to a collection needs the name part of the name/value submitted in the form back to the server to follow a certain convention. The EditorFor(m => m[i].IsAdmin) code makes the name be the correct name expected by the MVC model binders.

Comment: But then I lose the ability to identify Users by their username, so whoever is using this system won't know who they're editing.

Comment: Why?  The individual user names will still be displayed.